# Image height not scaling in internet explorer using img tag

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Basically my issue can be seen by going [here](http://qcshots.com/photos) using internet explorer.

works perfectly fine in all other browsers (chrome has little blue squares that show up next to them for what ever reason, but that's not as big of a concern.

The code below is what I'm using.

```
<a rel="lightbox[vans]" href="../images/photos/IMG10-L.jpg" >
<img style=" border: 4px white solid; margin: 5px" width="200px" height="auto" alt="" src="../images/photos/thumb/IMG10.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need NOT to declare the height if you declare the width of an image to override its real size, so your code should look like this:

```
<img style=" border: 4px white solid; margin: 5px" width="200px" alt="" src="../images/photos/thumb/IMG10.jpg" alt="" />
```

(also I added alt and closed the img tag to make your code valid)

Comment: It was because i hadn't closed the tag properly, wouldn't have noticed unless you had said something, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`auto` is not valid `img` attribute value. I guess you can leave it undefined and it would work well.

Comment: leaving it undefined does nothing, I've even tried changing it to 137px but it does nothing...